# How are these people able to build their own Linux distro from scratch?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, operating-systems, kernel

I have greedy of building my own Linux distro as such like Ubuntu, Mint or Fedora. I went through Google to know better of how they are made, but unfortunately I was so unlucky.

I found "Linux from Scratch" tutorials, but some experts say that it is not so useful for building a distro.

I wonder how these OS Ubuntu etc.. are made. I mean there are lots of Linux based Operating Systems there and atleast one new release in a week. How are they able to do this? I mean where did they start from?

Am I the only one without a trace of where to start from?

I hope you experts could help me find a solution. I have no other source to seek information from..

Comment: Have you seen this?: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/

Comment: yes, but I am not sure about it. Its just like going on installing packages

Comment: A lot of linux releases are based on existing distros - for example, Ubuntu is based on Debian, Mint is based on Ubuntu. At the base level, people take the Linux kernal, add their desired packages ("installing packages") and make a Linux distro as you know it. Linux is very modular and uses these individual packages to build up a complete system.

Comment: They started with the Linux code, developed a plan or vision of what they want Linux to do, and then began working in that direction. You would have to do the same thing to follow in their footsteps. They all started with research, and pandering to us is not a good way to start. Google is your friend and will show you many, many sources to get information from where it is already spelled out clearly.

Answer (score 2):

Well, a Linux System is pretty modular.

You have the Kernel, the Coreutilities (ls, cd , cat, ...), a Windowmanager, UserProgramms (Firefox, Texteditor), audioservices (Pulseaudio), a package manager and many more.
But to combine them into your own distro, you have to know a lot about each of these components.

It is easier to modify an existing distro. The simplest approach would be to take a distro image of your choice, unpack it and change the files (new background, other sounds or even other binaries) and then re-pack it.

If you really want to start from scratch: Have you read the book about it? 
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/downloads/stable/LFS-BOOK-7.10.pdf